# How to solve the issue "Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer" with Keras API?

Tags: keras, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I would like to learn how to make a chatbot with AI. I found this [tutorial](https://handsonai.medium.com/build-a-chat-bot-from-scratch-using-python-and-tensorflow-fd189bcfae45). I used a small text file to check if my Python script was working and now I want to use a bigger text input. The content of the file is as follows:

```
This compiler has no dedicated message for sign compare.
Code lines with implicit cast due to sign conversion usually generate an informational message "C0005 (I)  
Precision lost".Renesas sign -compare equivalent
```

In the first step, I perform preprocessing, remove stop words, lowercase etc. and then I end up with a list for the 2nd and 3rd line of the file as follows:

```
['code', 'line', 'implicit', 'cast', 'due', 'sign', 'conversion', 'usually', 'generate', 'informational', 'message', '``', 'c0005']
```

Next, I perform tokenization with the following result:

```py
{'<OOV>': 1, 'sign': 2, 'message': 3, 'compiler': 4, 'dedicated': 5, 'compare': 6, 'code': 7, 'line': 8, 'implicit': 9, 'cast': 10, 'due': 11, 'conversion': 12, 'usually': 13, 'generate': 14, 'informational': 15, '``': 16, 'c0005': 17, 'precision': 18, 'lost': 19, "''": 20, '.renesas': 21, '-compare': 22, 'equivalent': 23}
```

Afterwards, I have sequences and padded sequences with the following output:

```
[[4, 5, 3, 2, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15, 3, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 2, 22, 23]]
```

And padded:

```
[[ 4  5  3  2  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11  2 12 13 14 15  3 16 17  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0]
 [18 19 20 21  2 22 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0  0  0  0]]
```

Finally, I use this command to train the model:

```py
training_data = padded_sequences[:training_size] 
training_labels = padded_sequences[:training_size]

history = model.fit(training_data, training_labels,batch_size=1, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=3)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: labels.shape must equal logits.shape except for the last dimension.
Received: labels.shape=(100,) and logits.shape=(1, 100)
```

Can anyone explain what the error is and help me fix it? I think the array size has an issue but I cannot understand exactly what the problem is.

You can also find all the Python code [here](https://justpaste.it/7wtsl/pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a simple problem and it can be fixed by giving the correct shape for your labels (please provide the shapes of training_data and training_labels), so as I can see you are missing the batch (batch_size=1) dimension in your training_labels which can be done by:

```
training_data = padded_sequences[:training_size] 
training_labels = padded_sequences[:training_size]
training_labels = np.expand_dims(training_labels, axis=0)  # add batch axis
```

So would try this and see if it resolves it.

Otherwise please always provide your model summary to read the layers and their shape, this you can do by writing

```
model.summary()
```

EDIT: I printed the model summary from your code (it is totally different than what you gave in the comment):

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 100, 64)           6400      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 100, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 96, 64)            20544     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 24, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 64)                33024     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               6500      
=================================================================
Total params: 70,628
Trainable params: 70,628
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As you can see the output of your model must be 100, while your labels are now 20, so would you check this again.

Comment: I will try it asap, thnx.

Comment: now have a new error `ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 3
  y sizes: 1
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.`

Comment: Would you provide the shapes of x and y, also the summary of your model.

Comment: I have posted in the main question the link with all my code.

Comment: Well first put the verbose here to 1 NOT 3: history = model.fit(training_data, training_labels,batch_size=1, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=3).
Second, please provide the training shapes and model summary:
print("training_data", training_data.shape)
print("training_labels", training_labels.shape)
model.summary()

Comment: `training_data (3, 20)

    training_labels (3, 20)

    Model: "sequential"

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 20, 64)            1536
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 20, 64)            0
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 16, 128)           41088
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 4, 128)           0
 )lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 128)               131584
dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 129
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 24)                48`